# How to use dynamic values in URI endpoints in apache camel XML configuration

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I am using apache camel to create routes between endpoints where through one URI (API Gateway) running on Tomcat on one port, I am mapping to another URI running on Tomcat on different domain and port.

```
<bean id="hostnameVerifier" class="org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier" />
...
<camel:sslContextParameters id="ssl">
    <camel:keyManagers keyPassword="password">
        <camel:keyStore ... />
    </camel:keyManagers>
    <camel:trustManagers>
        <camel:keyStore ... />
    </camel:trustManagers>
</camel:sslContextParameters>
    ....

<rest path="/MyService" consumes="application/json" produces="application/json">

    <post uri="/login">
        <description>Authenticate User</description>
        <route streamCache="true">
            <to
                uri="https4://domain-b:9000/Auth/user/login?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;sslContextParametersRef=ssl&amp;x509HostnameVerifier=hostnameVerifier" />
        </route>
    </post>
    ...
</rest>
```

Now as far as I am hardcoding the domain-b in my to endpoints, things are working fine. Problem comes when I have to dynamically fill that value from an input from some configuration file.

This is how I am trying to achieve the same -

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:${LOCATION_PATH}propsfile.properties"/>
</bean>
```

The name of the properties key is "domain", now in my end points defintion I am writing the same as -

```
<to
    uri="https4://${properties.domain}:9000/Auth/user/login?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;sslContextParametersRef=ssl&amp;x509HostnameVerifier=hostnameVerifier" />
```

Basically after loading the properties in a bean named properties, I am trying to replace the domain-b with ${properties.domain} or #{properties.domain}, but does not seem to be working.

If anyone can suggest, in XML based config only, how can I read the URL domain from the properties file, that will be really awesome.

-AJ

Comment: did you try `uri="https4://{{properties.domain}}:9000` ? inside camel route element properties are available like that.

Comment: let me check and update. thanks

Comment: It did not work that way, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use property place holder to achieve dynamic uri the way you want.

**For example:**

```
<camelContext ...>
   <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="YOUR_PROPERTY_FILE_LOCATION"/>
</camelContext>
```

And then try with

```
<to uri="https4://{{properties.domain}}:9000/.......>
```

Note: When you are configuring your property file using spring bean *"PropertiesComponent"*, you have to use camel **[Property](http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html#UsingPropertyPlaceholder-ExamplesUsingPropertiesComponent)** component inside your camel route to achieve dynamic value loading.

Answer (score 0):

Since Camel 2.16

We can use

```
.from("file://path")
.toD("file://folder/${file:onlyname}")
```

We can use file